# Input lag and micro-stutter using NVidia's On-demand mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, lag

I recently switched to Ubuntu 19.10 and started using that shiny On-demand mode from NVidia for Prime (Optimus laptops). I am using mostly default ubuntu settings.

**I experience intense micro-stutters and a constant input lag, how should I go about fixing this issue ?**

Steam is started using the following command : `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia steam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my CPU Power Governor to Performance did the trick. It is on power-saving mode by default, which slowly scales up the power but scales it down quickly. I hope this can help others !

Answer (score -1):

Which version of the Nvidia drivers are you using?

Based on https://askubuntu.com/q/1186234/925753, the default Nvidia driver in 19.10, the 430 series doesn't support the `on-demand` mode. You have to update to `nvidia-driver-435`. Assuming your nvidia driver doesn't work, you're gaming on the Intel GPU, which could be responsible for the micro stutters input lag.

Comment: I am using nvidia-driver-435. dGPU support has been verified through multiple methods (command-line, in steam, and FPS difference). I have yet to try using v440

Comment: I've done some testing and I get flashing on some textures on certain arenas in Rocket League, but I don't get any noticeable input lag except for a few seconds after switching to an Nvidia powered full screen application. You might be onto a performance bottleneck

Comment: Maybe. I just switched my CPU governor to performance, I'll reboot and test again. Drivers v440 didn't help.